# i want to invalidate/expire Auth0 token id once user is logout from client side

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, access-token, auth0

i want to invalidate Auth0 Token id once user is logout from the client side. once logout is happens auth0 token which is used for exchanging and validating between Angular and Spring boot application should no longer validate by `JwtVerifier` it should reject the token id. and return with unauthorized.

i am not using spring boot security. all the token verification happens at `AuthorizationRequestFilter` level.

Comment: From [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/invalidating-an-access-token-when-user-logs-out/48365): *"Access tokens cannot be invalidated: they are designed to be self contained, not requiring a check with Auth0 to validate, so there is no way to invalidate them.

For this reason, access tokens should have a short lifetime."*

Comment: And from the [actual documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/revoke-tokens): *"Once issued, access tokens and ID tokens cannot be revoked in the same way as cookies with session IDs for server-side sessions.

As a result, tokens should be issued for relatively short periods, and then refreshed periodically if the user remains active."*

Comment: is there any ways for alternate ways for this approch @RobertHarvey

Comment: None that involve invalidation of the token.

Comment: If you're in control of the expiration time, you should make the access token short-lived, to minimize the time that it is valid after logout.

Comment: is there any API exists for minimize the time for the token id. @jps

Comment: My question was if you're in control of the process that creates the token and can you influence the creation, e.g. by configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. See https://community.auth0.com/t/invalidating-an-access-token-when-user-logs-out/48365